# Lookup react, bring the information from my getSituations to the list comboBox

Tags: reactjs

I have two forms divided by Paper.
A registration form and the other form with the list of all who are registered.
But I need to do a lookup to be able to edit the people I have already registered.
I have a comboBox that lists the function with the fields related to the situation, but I'm not able to add the lookup with the information, in my code the constant that I store the data is empty, but the function is not empty.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await props.getClients();
      const situacao = await getSituations(); //(local function) getSituations(): Promise<void> 

      console.log(situacao);

      return situacao;  
    })();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but you seem to be trying to fetch data that will be used as a property in elements rendered by your React component. This is a broad subject and without you providing more detail, it's not possible to answer it. There are many resources on how to implement this, such as https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data. Please follow those instructions and edit your question to be more specific, or delete it.